# Category filter isn't properly removing divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling to get my code to remove not only everything within the div, but the div as well (div with gradient background). At the moment it is just removing the content within the div when I select a button to filter the content that will be displayed. The class name that is used to remove and display the content is the "column" class within the "grid-item-container2" div. Any suggestions?

```css
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
} /* Sets the way the headstone category divs are displayed (horizontally) 
and allows for them to wrap round each other when screen adjusting */

.grid-item2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.wrapping-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: currentColor;
} /* Allows the user to be able to click anywhere within the headstone category div to access the href link */

.grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} /* Adds styling, sets sizing and sets transition speed of the headstone category div */

.grid-item-container2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-image-top2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  max-height: 575px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  cursor: pointer;
} /* Sets sizing and positioning of the images within the headstone category divs. 
This also removes the white background of each image (mix-blend-mode: multiply;) */ 

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/heartmemorials/images/heart2.jpg");
  transform: scaleX(-1);
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the lawn memorials */

.grid-image-top2.churchyard-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn12.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the churchyard memorials */

.grid-image-top2.children-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn16.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the children memorials */

.grid-image-top2.heart-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn30.jpg"); 
  transform: scaleX(-1);
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the heart memorials */

.grid-item2:hover .grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 1.5% 1.5%;
  margin: -1.5% -1.5%;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
} /* Adds the padding for when users hover over the headstone category div. Also adds gradient to the small extra space added within the padding */





/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Browse Memorials</h1>

<!-- MAIN (Center website) -->
<div class="main">
<hr>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('lawn')"> Lawn Memorials</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('churchyard')"> Churchyard Memorials</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('children')"> Children Memorials</button>
</div><hr>


<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
<div class="grid-row"> <!-- Start of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->   
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <span class="centered project-image-bg rex-ray-image"></span>
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
            
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
          <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column churchyard"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <span class="centered project-image-bg sputnik-image"></span>
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
              
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div --> 
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column children"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 children-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg edgex-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column churchyard"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 heart-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg openswitch-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg scaleio-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div>


<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the `.column`. Move your `display:none` style to `.grid-item2`:

```
.grid-item2 {
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}
```

Then, in your `filterSelection` function, toggle the class on `.parentElement.parentElement`:

```
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i].parentElement.parentElement, "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i].parentElement.parentElement, "show");
  }
}
```

Here's your snippet modified:

```css
.grid-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
} /* Sets the way the headstone category divs are displayed (horizontally) 
and allows for them to wrap round each other when screen adjusting */

.grid-item2 {
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} /* Sets padding between headstone category divs, sets sizing and sets for row to be 5 divs */

.wrapping-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: currentColor;
} /* Allows the user to be able to click anywhere within the headstone category div to access the href link */

.grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
  -moz-box-sizing: initial;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  transition: padding 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), margin 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1), box-shadow 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.9,1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} /* Adds styling, sets sizing and sets transition speed of the headstone category div */

.grid-item-container2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} /* Allows content to use full width and height of the headstone category div. Also styles the div. */

.grid-image-top2 {
  min-height: 375px;
  max-height: 575px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin: 5%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  cursor: pointer;
} /* Sets sizing and positioning of the images within the headstone category divs. 
This also removes the white background of each image (mix-blend-mode: multiply;) */ 

.grid-image-top2.lawn-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/heartmemorials/images/heart2.jpg");
  transform: scaleX(-1);
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the lawn memorials */

.grid-image-top2.churchyard-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn12.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the churchyard memorials */

.grid-image-top2.children-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn16.jpg");
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the children memorials */

.grid-image-top2.heart-memorials {
  background-image: url("https://www.kayparkmemorials.com/memorials/lawnmemorials/images/lawn30.jpg"); 
  transform: scaleX(-1);
} /* Adds image to headstone category div for the heart memorials */

.grid-item2:hover .grid-item-wrapper {
  padding: 1.5% 1.5%;
  margin: -1.5% -1.5%;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 219, 219) , rgb(252, 252, 250));
} /* Adds the padding for when users hover over the headstone category div. Also adds gradient to the small extra space added within the padding */





/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item2 {
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Browse Memorials</h1>

<!-- MAIN (Center website) -->
<div class="main">
<hr>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('lawn')"> Lawn Memorials</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('churchyard')"> Churchyard Memorials</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('children')"> Children Memorials</button>
</div><hr>


<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
<div class="grid-row"> <!-- Start of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2 "> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->   
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 lawn-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <span class="centered project-image-bg rex-ray-image"></span>
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
            
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
      <div class="grid-item2 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
        <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->      
          <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-item-container2 column churchyard"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                <span class="centered project-image-bg sputnik-image"></span>
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
              
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
        <div class="grid-item2 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
          <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div --> 
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column children"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 children-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg edgex-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column churchyard"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 heart-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg openswitch-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
          <div class="grid-item2 show"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <a class="wrapping-link" href="#"></a> <!-- Takes user to the designated link when user's click on the headstone category div -->
            <div class="grid-item-wrapper"> <!-- Start of div -->
              <div class="grid-item-container2 column lawn"> <!-- Start of div -->
            <div class="grid-image-top2 churchyard-memorials content"> <!-- Start of div -->
                  <span class="centered project-image-bg scaleio-image"></span>
                </div> <!-- End of div -->
                
              </div> <!-- End of div -->
            </div> <!-- End of div -->
          </div> <!-- End of div -->
        </div> <!-- End of div -->
      </div> <!-- End of div -->
</div>


<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i].parentElement.parentElement, "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i].parentElement.parentElement, "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>
```